# Create a 2 different Posts in 2 different custom post type after function

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a 2 different posts in 2 different post types. What i am trying to achieve is to have 2 unique posts, and if a button is clicked twice, it shouldn't create the post again.

```
<?
$custom_title = $company_name . '-' . $formindex;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'dogovori',
    'post_title' => $custom_title,
    'post_name' => $company_name,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_content' => $content_dogovor,
);
$post_id = post_exists($custom_title) or wp_insert_post($args);

$args1 = array(
    'post_type' => 'svidetelstva',
    'post_title' => $custom_title,
    'post_name' => $company_name,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_content' => $content_dogovor,
);
$post_id1 = post_exists($custom_title) or wp_insert_post($args1);
```

This is what i am using as a code. It works perfectly and creates the post only in 'dogovori'. What i want is to create at the same time in 'svidetelstva' as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `post_exists` does not pay any attention to your post type. So first you are inserting a new post with a custom title. When you check if a post exists the second time, it finds the first post you inserted.

Please reference this SA answer to check if a specific custom post exists with a title:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/300151

Comment: Yes i just saw that, but this :
'code' if (get_page_by_title('Some Title', OBJECT, 'post_type')) {
    // Exists
}'
i want to do it if doesn't exists, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you can use this: ```if ( ! get_page_by_title...``` which would check if it doesn't exist.